# Simulate multiple default members in Calendar dimension

Tags: ssas, default, member, dimension

I'm implementing a Calendar dimension that allows us to incorporate multiple types of calendar (Gregorian, Fiscal, CustomerX...) per [Dave Fackler's great article](http://davefackler.blogspot.com/2008/05/handling-multiple-calendars-with-m2m.html) using many-to-many relationships.  The gist of it is that at the top of the hierarchy (which specific calendar system you're using), the IsAggregatable property should be set to false to prevent improper aggregations across all calendars, which means that you need to set a specific default member as [All] has been removed.  So , I can choose &[Gregorian] in my case.  The problem is that I also need to have a default of "*yesterday*".  I can easily set either/or [Gregorian] for calendar type or "yesterday" for the bottom of the hierarchy in MDX, but not both.  I've read all about how dimensions can have only one default member, but I really need to set both.  Can anyone direct me?

Much thanks!